# sudo docker container prune recovery

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I ran the command:
**sudo docker container prune**

I had a stopped postgres sql container and the data was in the container only. Is there any way to recover this data?

These are the docker events:

```
2024-03-28T16:13:33.986659248+05:30 container destroy 9df67ddcc79f895e4f4922187d32a2922520d6f2a94fb5b0bad60d1fb1965894 (image=postgres, name=postgres-container)
2024-03-28T16:13:34.025769814+05:30 container destroy bc6c56e1953bda5a6fd48c741ab8bffd38e1c5c176f5b82f6166424c5f76121e (com.microsoft.product=Microsoft SQL Server, com.microsoft.version=16.0.4105.2, image=mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest, name=sql, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, org.opencontainers.image.version=22.04, vendor=Microsoft)
2024-03-28T16:13:34.064037404+05:30 container destroy 9d6ecf7fc406599ee846a16938408c8dfbebe0deb2e8d063ac2fdaa3efa070fe (image=blazr-api, name=blazr-container)
2024-03-28T16:13:34.064048454+05:30 container prune  (reclaimed=1984382618)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not easily but file recovery tools might help but it all depends on your platform

Comment: This was running on a ubuntu server.

Comment: Please suggest some recovery tools.

Comment: That’s not an appropriate question for stack overflow